# Representación gráfica en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

EDITO CON LA SOLUCIÓN (LA HE ENCONTRADO AL TIEMPO)

Buenas estoy intentando representar unos valores que me llegan de un dispositivo en una gráfica, para ver como varían, el código donde se encuentra el Main es:

```
public class Servidor {
private static double aceleracion;


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    try {       
            //Obtención de la aceleración total
            aceleracion= Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2)+Math.pow(y, 2)+Math.pow(z, 2));       
            senal.add(aceleracion);//pasar los datos a un ArrayList
            System.out.println(aceleracion);

            GraficaMagnitud gm=new GraficaMagnitud("Aceleracion");
            gm.addValue(aceleracion);
    }

     } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Y donde se encuentra GraficaMagnitud, con el código correcto:

public class GraficaMagnitud extends javax.swing.JFrame{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private XYSeries aceleracion;
private JFreeChart chart; 
public GraficaMagnitud(ArrayList<Double> aceleraciones, String title) { 
    aceleracion = new XYSeries("Aceleracion"); 
    XYSeriesCollection xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(); 
    xyDataset.addSeries(aceleracion); 
    for(Double er : aceleraciones) aceleracion.add(aceleracion.getItemCount(), er); 
    chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title,"Muestras", "aceleracion", xyDataset); 
    ChartPanel chartPanel = (ChartPanel) createDemoPanel(chart); 
    if(chartPanel != null){ 
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270)); 
        chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(true); chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(true); 
        setContentPane(chartPanel); this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        this.pack(); 
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(this); this.setVisible(true); 
        }
    }
private JPanel createDemoPanel(JFreeChart chart) { 
    try{ 
        if(chart != null){ 
            ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart); 
            panel.setFillZoomRectangle(true); 
            panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true); 
            return panel; }else return null; 
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null; 
            } 
    } 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya se dibuja bien la gráfica como veis

Edito más que nada por si a alguien alguna vez le surge el mismo problema o parecido y pueda ayudarse en mi código para guiarse

Un saludo

Comment: Buenas, sería deseable que proporcionaras un [mcve], concentrándote en la parte que quieres verificar, para eliminar posibles factores externos (por ejemplo, que los datos que te llegan por la red no son los que crees, o que solo estes pasando un único punto a la gráfica, etc.)

Comment: Hola, no se si he entendido muy bien tu mensaje, he resumido la parte del main (ya que se que el resto funciona), pero de la clase GraficaMagnitud no se que verificarte porque no la entiendo, por eso dejo todo el código, porque no se que parte es importante para entender el error, un saludo

Comment: Quiero decir que si solo pruebas el sistema entero igual buscas un error donde no es, pero que si pones el código que te interesa en un programa más pequeño y controlado **que funcione** puedes ver mejor qué información estás pasando a la clase (qué valores, cuántos valores, etc.)